# How can i bridge and display images from realsense d435 camera?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner in ros. I am looking to get image frames from an Intel Realsense D435 camera, bridge and show the image (with opencv) . At the same time, I look to print/ log out the information from the camera. After running code, the program continuously runs (due to rospy.spin() function) but does not print out anything.

Where could I be going wrong with the code?
Could someone please explain a bit on how to use the ros messages in a  python code. I am writing a subscriber node.'

```
class Depth_Retriever():
    def __init__(self):
 
        self.bridge = CvBridge()

        self.sub = rospy.Subscriber('/camera/depth/image_rect_raw',Image,callback)

    def callback(self,ros_pics):
        try: 
            my_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(ros_pics, encoding = "passthrough")

        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print("CvBridge could not convert images from realsense to opencv")
        height,width, channels = my_image.shape
        my_height = my_image.shape[0]
        print(my_height)
         
        self.vert_len = ros_pics.height # retrieve height information from Image msg
        print(self.vert_len)


def main():
    rospy.init_node("Depth",anonymous = True)
 
    rospy.spin()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Thank you for help in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354676/how-can-i-bridge-and-display-images-from-realsense-d435-camera?/) by [Anonymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/44869/anonymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The callback is never accessed. Change

`self.sub = rospy.Subscriber('/camera/depth/image_rect_raw',Image,callback)`

to

`self.sub = rospy.Subscriber('/camera/depth/image_rect_raw', Image, self.callback)`

Some additional comments:

- If you just want to view images, use [rqt_image_view](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_image_view) instead
- use [ROS logging](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Logging) instead of prints, that way you can use all the tools associated with it
- consider using a linter, I see several [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations ;)

---

Originally posted by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) with karma: 464 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anonymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/44869/anonymous/) on 2020-06-16**:
Thank you so much for the response. I was able to get the code to work. However, when I use cv2.imshow() to display the image, I receive a black image. If I change the datatype from "passthrough" ,when bridging, to other datatype such as "bgr8" it fails to convert.  What could be the cause of this black image?

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2020-06-16**:
Don't forget to accept the answer then so the question shows as resolved. What do you see when you run `rqt_image_view`? And what is the actual encoding (what you call datatype)? It has to be an encoding supported by `cv`. And what is the actual error you're getting?

**Comment by [Anonymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/44869/anonymous/) on 2020-06-18**:
After running the rqt_image_view I realized I was subscribing to the wrong topic. The data encoding was "passthrough". It currently works. Thank you.

**Comment by [danielcjacobs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62566/danielcjacobs/) on 2020-11-03**:
I'm having the same problem, how did you fix it?